# Using Automapper in Complex Type

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a backend properties on EF like this

```
 public partial class PatientSurveyQuestion
    {
        public PatientSurveyQuestion()
        {
            this.PatientSurveyQuestionAnswers = new HashSet<PatientSurveyQuestionAnswer>();
            this.PatientSurveyReplies = new HashSet<PatientSurveyReply>();
        }

        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PointID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> QuestionType { get; set; }

        public virtual PatientSurveyPoint PatientSurveyPoint { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PatientSurveyQuestionAnswer> PatientSurveyQuestionAnswers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PatientSurveyReply> PatientSurveyReplies { get; set; }
    }

  public partial class PatientSurveyQuestionAnswer
    {
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public int AnswerID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreayed { get; set; }

        public virtual PatientSurveyAnswer PatientSurveyAnswer { get; set; }
        public virtual PatientSurveyQuestion PatientSurveyQuestion { get; set; }
    }
```

and a join class

```
  public class PatientQS
    {

        public PatientSurveyQuestion Question { get; set; }
        public List<PatientSurveyAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have the same classes without references and virtual functions for WFC

```
[DataContract]
public class Question
{
    [DataMember]
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> PointID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> QuestionType { get; set; }
}

   [DataContract]
    public class Answers
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int AnswerID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }

   [DataContract]
    public class QuestionsAnswers
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Question Question { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Answers> Answers{ get; set; }
    }
```

Then I ran a query to get data and use autopmaper

```
   var quesans = (from c in db.PatientSurveyQuestions
                       from v in db.PatientSurveyQuestionAnswers
                       where c.QuestionID == v.QuestionID && c.PointID == pointID
                       select new {c, ans=c.PatientSurveyQuestionAnswers.Select(n=>n.PatientSurveyAnswer)}).ToList().Select(c => new PatientQS { Question = c.c, Answers = c.ans.ToList() }).ToList();
                        Mapper.CreateMap<PatientSurveyAnswer, Answers>();
                        Mapper.CreateMap<PatientQS, QuestionsAnswers>().ForMember(c=>c.Answers, m=>m.MapFrom(
                              q=>Mapper.Map<List<PatientSurveyAnswer>, List<Answers>>(q.Answers)
                            ));
                        QuestionsAnswers q2 = Mapper.Map<QuestionsAnswers>(quesans);
```

but automapper gives me an error

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
>   List`1 -> QuestionsAnswers
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[PatientService1.PROP.PatientQS, PatientService1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> PatientService1.PROP.QuestionsAnswers
>
> Destination path:
>   QuestionsAnswers
>
> Source value:
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PatientService1.PROP.PatientQS]

am i doing something wrong or is it really not supported?

Comment: You haven't provided a mapping from a list to a `QuestionsAnswers`. Also, why are your `CreateMap<>` calls in the middle of the query?

Comment: it not part of the query and mapping is provided

Comment: Where is your `CreateMap<>` call that maps between `QuestionsAnswers` and a list? I can't see it there..

Comment: QuestionsAnswers is itself a list and mapping is there with specifically mapping just the answer list property

Comment: Un-linq code until you find the line which throws the exception. Then fix it. Then re-linq code.